# C Declaring array of char*

Tags: c

I thought you could declare an array, and then later initilze it.

Like so

```
char* myArray[3];


//CODE INBETWEEN 

myArray[3] = {

            "blah",
            "blah",
            "blah"};
```

Comment: You're declaring an array of character pointers. Each pointer would need to point to a dynamic or static buffer before you can use strcpy() or other string operations to change the contents.

Comment: So I have to initlize and declare at the same time?>

Answer (score 21):

Nope, you can only initialize an array when you first declare it.  The reason is that arrays are not modifiable lvalues.

In your case:

```
char *array[] = {"blah", "blah", "blah"};
```

You don't need to specify the size, but you can if you want.  However, the size can't be less than 3 in this case.  Also, the three strings are written to read-only memory so something like `array[1][2] = 'c'` to change the 2nd "blah" to "blch" will normally result in a segfault.

Comment: More precisely, arrays in most contexts evaluate to rvalues, not lvalues, and assignment to an rvalue is not allowed.

Comment: Actually, your explanation is probably more correct. Edited my post.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said you can only use initialisers when the variable is declared.  The closest way to do what you want is:

```
char *myArray[3];

/* CODE INBETWEEN */

{
    static const char *tmp[3] = {
            "blah",
            "blah",
            "blah" };
    memcpy(myArray, tmp, sizeof myArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can declare an array and then later initialize it.
However, there is an exception here.
You are declaring a **character pointer array** (which worked fine).
And, then you are **instantiating constant strings to assign them to the array**.

That is where the problem starts.
Constant strings are just compiler primitives that do not get any addressable memory location in the way you have used them. They can be assigned right at the array initialization time (as `Mike` has shown); that will instruct the compiler to allocate them as constants available at run-time and allow an initialization when the scope of `myArray` starts.

---

What you have tried would have worked well with

```
int numberArray[3];
// code here
numberArray[0] = 1;
numberArray[1] = 2;
numberArray[2] = 3;
```

It helps to note that a character pointer and a string instance are two different entities; the first can point to the second.

Comment: In your example you are not initializing the values. You are simply setting the value. An optimizer may turn what you wrote in to initialization but there is no guarantee.

Comment: @Jared, I'll take your down-vote and comment in the spirit of the exact meaning of `initialization`. However, I do not think the question meant the word in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

You thought wrong. Initialization is only possible *at* declaration. After that, you can only assign individual values.

Answer (score 0):

It's an initializer expression. Can't have that code in between, got to be used on the line withe declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear which *real world problem* you're trying to solve, here...

> I thought you could declare an array,

... that is possible in so many ways, but for the sake of this question I want to focus on declaring an array inside of a `struct`.

```
struct my_struct {
    char *my_array[3];
};
```

> and then later initilze it.
>
> Like so

```
struct my_struct fubar;
fubar = (struct my_struct) { { "hello", "world" } };
```

Technically speaking this is initialisation of a *different* array (within an anonymous object) followed by an assignment of the entire `struct`. It *might* be useful to solve your *real world problem* (whatever that is)... but hopefully it will ultimately be useful for someone else later on to know that you can assign `struct`s with arrays inside of them...