# Using the items of a char** (after post-declaration initialization)

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, pipe

As **caf** talked about it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1113041/1354779, 
there is a way to use initialisers when the variable is declared to initialize an array already declared.
That is great, and I now would like to know if there is a way to use every item of the array, one by one.

I use that to pass on a list of commands through a pipe, and I know that *this* works:

```
char* script[]={"report blabla","report bla"};
char line[200];
char** command;
for (command = script ; **command ; **command ? command++ : 0){
    if (**command){
        SendCommand(*command, line, sizeof(line));
    }   
}
```

But when I try my code below, I get an "Unhandled exception at 0x778915de in pipe_GWB9.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc" :

```
char* request[] = {"report watact"};
char line[200];
// [...] Other code [...]
static const char *tmp[8] = 
  {
  "report molality H+",
  "report molality Cl-",
  "report molality Ca++",
  "report molality Mg++",
  "report molality K+",
  "report molality Fe++",
  "report molality SO4--",
  "report molality Na+"
  }; 
  memcpy(request, tmp, sizeof request);
char** command;
command=request;
SendCommand(*command, line, sizeof(line));
// Until here, everything works great.
**command ? command++ : 0;
SendCommand(*command, line, sizeof(line));
// But THAT doesn't work!!
```

Would you be able to help me calling for the other items of the array *request*?

Thanks

Comment: The question you linked to is for C code, however you tagged this as C++, any reason why you're not using `std::string`?

Comment: I re-tagged as C because there is nothing C++ about this code.

Comment: My bad. No, I just have a `using namespace std;` that I didn't mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* request[] = {"report watact"};
```

`request` is an array of pointers to char which contains 1 element.

```
static const char *tmp[8] = 
  {
  "report molality H+",
  "report molality Cl-",
  "report molality Ca++",
  "report molality Mg++",
  "report molality K+",
  "report molality Fe++",
  "report molality SO4--",
  "report molality Na+"
  };
```

`tmp` is an array of pointers to `char` with 8 elements.

```
memcpy(request, tmp, sizeof request);
```

You copy the first four bytes (assuming `sizeof request == 4`) from `tmp` into `request`, i.e., you copy the first element of `tmp` into the first element of `request`.

```
char** command;
command=request;
```

Simple enough; `command` now points to the first (and only!) element of `request`.

```
**command ? command++ : 0;
```

Oops.  You just ran past the bounds of `command` (`request`) because `request` contains only a single element.  You then dereference it when calling `SendCommand` on the next line, which gives you your seg fault.  Note that anything could happen here because you are invoking UB.

For example, what *may* happen if you cut out the code between the two arrays is that the string `"report molality H+"` is sent twice because incrementing the pointer past the bounds of `request` may very well just plop you onto the beginning `tmp`.

If you want to copy all of `tmp` into `request` then you need to make sure the two arrays are of the same size (or at least, that `request` is as large as `tmp`).

As an aside, this ternary expression is a bit silly:

```
**command ? command++ : 0;
```

You only care about one branch, so why use a ternary at all? Prefer:

```
if(**command)
    command++;
```

That said, this is not a safe way to check the bounds of your array (as you found out).  You are treating the array of pointers as if it were a pointer to char, i.e., scan until you find the NULL terminator.

There is no NULL terminator for an array, you simply end up walking past its boundaries and invoking undefined behavior, so you need to keep track of the size separately and check against that.

Comment: Wow, thank you SO much, that makes much more sense right now. I didn't get the relationship between the array of pointers and the pointer to char... thanks again